# Terminologia usada após a Portaria 1488/2004?

Tags: gramática, recursos

Eu estava a ver a terminologia da [Portaria 1488/2004, de 24 de Dezembro](https://dre.tretas.org/dre/179681/portaria-1488-2004-de-24-de-dezembro) (vejam as [páginas 7308-7315 do anexo](https://files.dre.pt/1s/2004/12/300b00/73077315.pdf)) intitulada *"Terminologia Linguística para os Ensinos Básico e Secundário"*.

A pergunta é se há no presente alguma terminologia adoptada oficialmente em Portugal para estes níveis de ensino? Encontrei este [Dicionário Terminológico](http://dt.dge.mec.pt/index.php?id=n109) no site da Direcção-Geral de Educação que parece ser igual.

Para acrescentar alguma contexto está [aqui uma publicação](https://www.spra.pt/ministerio-da-educacao-suspende-a-experiencia-pedagogica-da-tlebs/) da época em que não é claro se a terminologia acabou por ser adoptada e se ela é vigente.

Comment: Se olharem com atenção para a data isto deve ter sido um presente de Natal :P

Comment: Via de regra é mais construtivo e cortês acompanhar um voto negativo por um comentário explicativo.

Comment: @stafusa (e aviso aos leitores) entretanto encontrei [um bom documento](http://www.esqm.pt/documentos/BE/DICIONARIOTERMINOLOGICO.pdf) que explica isto. Se eu tiver tempo tento hoje escrever uma resposta, se alguém quiser escrever antes de mim esteja à vontade.